# Блок с кнопками смешается вправо, когда я задаю margin

Tags: html, css

Всем здравствуйте, уважаемые разработчики.

У меня такой вопрос, есть блок с кнопками... И когда, я хочу задать им отступы (между 1-ой и 2-ой кнопкой), то у меня кнопки (обе) смешиваются вправо... Скажите пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

```css
/*Стили для кнопок */
.button__select__method {
  margin-top: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button__select {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #061e37;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 3s;
}

#button__select:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #061e37;
}
```

```html
<div class="button__select__method">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy__now" id="button__select" role="button">BUY NOW</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-try__for__free" id="button__select" role="button">TRY FOR FREE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Код ваш покажите

Comment: Задай кнопке с право отрицательный `margin`...

Answer (score -1):

Возможно у вас один и тот же класс прописан для кнопок и это влияет?
Так же можете классы новые задать и им прописать стили. 
(можно код)?

```
.button__select__method .btn-buy__now {margin-right:100px}
```

или

```
.button__select__method .btn-try__for__free{margin-left:100px;}
```

У вас имеются классы отдельные для каждой кнопки) можете так отдельно воздействовать

Comment: Ну так, я им и задал один класс для 2-х кнопок.. Просто, так верстать намного удобнее!

Comment: Или лучше будет установить последнему элементу/кнопке псевдокласс nth-child ?

Comment: Да, конечно! Сейчас предоставлю код!

Comment: Вот код на codepen.io: 
https://codepen.io/ibrahim-magomedrasulov/pen/GBqZQJ